# Why does Java not find the packages?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I try to get run the compile.sh of the Java code DictionaryPC I got from [GitHub.](https://github.com/rdoeffinger/DictionaryPC)
Everytime when I run it, I get the errors shown below. But the .class files which are allegedly missing do exist as the folders ../com/hughes/android/

The paths in compile.sh are set right.

```
../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/dictionary/engine/Dictionary.java:17: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.ContentResolver;
                      ^
../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/dictionary/engine/Dictionary.java:18: error: package android.support.v4.provider does not exist
import android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile;
                                  ^
../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/dictionary/engine/Dictionary.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
    private static DictionaryInfo getErrorDictionaryInfo(final DocumentFile file) {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class DocumentFile
  location: class Dictionary
../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/dictionary/engine/Dictionary.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
    public static DictionaryInfo getDictionaryInfo(final DocumentFile file, final ContentResolver r) {
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class DocumentFile
  location: class Dictionary
../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/dictionary/engine/Dictionary.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
    public static DictionaryInfo getDictionaryInfo(final DocumentFile file, final ContentResolver r) {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ContentResolver
  location: class Dictionary
5 errors
```

Comment: Do you have a classpath entry for ../com/hughes/ or just for ../. Maybe I'm wrong but I think you need the directory where the top level package (in your case 'android') specified on the classpath.

Comment: I tried to add an entry into the classpath, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or it may be my lack of skills of Java. I added:
`<classpathentry kind="src" path="../Dictionary/src/com/hughes/android/" />` 
But that entry didn't help. Note: _compile.sh_ & _.classpath_ are in folder DictionaryPC which is in same parent folder as Dictionary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm wrong. I've used Java for over 20 years but never Android so maybe I shouldn't have commented on this. I think (after a quick Internet search) that the classes that aren't found are part of the android API which have root package android.* not com.hughes.android.* (which is what I thought). I don't know how Android stuff is compiled (does it have its own equivalent of a JDK?) but I doubt you can just use the regular Oracle/OpenJDK for this if that's what your trying to do.